# Icecast, Ices2 and HTTPS

Tags: https, lets-encrypt, icecast

I want to set up icecast (version 2.4.99.2) with HTTPS. I have tried the Debian version of icecast, as well as compiled from source.

Here is some relevant info:

/etc/icecast2/icecast.xml:

```
<listen-socket>
  <port>8000</port>
</listen-socket>
<listen-socket>
  <port>8443</port>
  <ssl>1</ssl>
</listen-socket>

<http-headers>
  <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
</http-headers>

<paths>
  <basedir>/usr/share/icecast2</basedir>
  <logdir>/var/log/icecast2</logdir>
  <webroot>/usr/share/icecast2/web</webroot>
  <adminroot>/usr/share/icecast2/admin</adminroot>
  <alias source="/" destination="/status.xsl"/>
  <ssl-certificate>/usr/share/icecast2/web/bundle.pem</ssl-certificate>
  <ssl-private-key>/usr/share/icecast2/web/bundle.pem</ssl-private-key>
</paths>
```

The bundle.pem file contains the privkey.pem and fullchain.pem files
of the dehydrated (let's encrypt) certificates, in this order.

ices2 config file:

```
<instance>
  <port>8443</port>
</instance>
```

with 8000 (HTTP) it works, not with 8443 (HTTPS).

Ports 8000 and 8443 are open on the firewall.

/var/log/icecast2/error.log

The error log file gives:

```
WARN tls/tls_ctx_new Invalid cert file /etc/icecast2/bundle.pem
```

What is the correct format for the .pem file?

I am thankful for any help!

Comment: The config snippet doesn't match the error message. Please make sure that the icecast2 user has read access to that file. Especially if this is generated by some letsencrypt client, then this might not be the case.

Comment: @ILoveCake You really don't want to put your certificate private key in the publicly accessible web root.

Comment: Good point! Thank you. I actually got it working. See the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. My certificate file was correct. It should contain the fullchain.pem and privkey.pem files. The only thing that was missing was to

1. move the certificate to a safe location
   and
2. give it the right ownership (icecast2/icecast)

Comment: Holy crap I've been banging my head against the keyboard for days trying to figure this out, I don't see any other answer mentioning the <ssl-private-key> section being necessary, and it seems weird it even would be since the fullchain + private key are both in bundle.pem.  Thank you though!!!